# Using an Array in Training Statements

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have an array of data I want to use. I want to put it in my training statements so my bag-of-words neural net can use it to train. My code looks like this:

```
training_statements={

for x in range(len(FinalFA))
FinalFA[x]:1,}
```

I get an invalid syntax error. Obviously it would be ridiculous to go through and write FinalFA[0]:1, FinalFA[1]:1, etc. How do I get my array to work within the brackets of "training_statements"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this sort of thing with arrays/lists and it worked when I placed the object before the loop so I think you can try to go like:

`training_statements={FinalFA[x]:1 for x in range(len(FinalFA))}`